# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings - Returns null on open with

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .NET Windows forms application to display images, which access the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` to get some settings.

It works fine on debug, and also when I click my compiled exe directly I can get my settings from the `app.config` file.

The issue comes when my application is not directly executed by me. When I associate a file extension with it, or manually do a *"Open With"* I get null accessing the`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Any ideas ?

Thank you so much

****EDIT*****

I found out the issue happens when I use the below code :

http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/

Which basically does the file association. I don't understand what's the root cause, but doing the file association manually on explorer the issue does not happen.

Thanks

Comment: There's no obvious way that this should fail, Windows still runs your .exe the same way the debugger does.  But then again, it is *very* unusual to not use `Properties.Settings` to retrieve application settings.  Meant to keep you ought of trouble like this.  You are doing something wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you please check the name of the config file in the application directory? The config name should be exename.exe.config and application name should be exename.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its working

**App.Config**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ExtensionSupported" value ="jpeg,jpg"/>
  </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

---

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if(args.Length>0)
                Application.Run(new Form1(args[0]));
            else
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string p;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        public Form1(string filePath):this()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loading file "+ filePath);
            CheckForAllowed(filePath);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
            DialogResult dr=  openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                CheckForAllowed(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        }

        private void CheckForAllowed(string filePath)
        {
            string appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtensionSupported"];
            MessageBox.Show("Allowed file types are " + appSetting);
            string[] allowedFileTypes = appSetting.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            string fileExtesnsion = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.')+1).Trim();



            if (allowedFileTypes.Contains(fileExtesnsion))
                label1.Text = "Allowed";
            else
                label1.Text = "Not allowed";
        }

    }
}
```